# How to show fractions in SQL/PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, fractions

I'd like to show fractions in PostgreSQL exactly as they are entered (as in no simplification or no turning into decimals). I do not have a preference on what kind of data type is used. I've tried variations of the following but to no avail:

```
SELECT to_char(2/32, '99/99') AS "Fraction";
```

This gives a result of "  /  0", but what I would like is "2/32".

In my actual situation the numerator and denominator are table field values, like '# enrolled people' / 'total # people'.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: This is an integer division operation, not a fraction. You're dividing `2` by `32` which results in 0 (because it's integer division). There's no simplification taking place.

Comment: So what's wrong with `select '2/32'`?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "exactly as they are entered"? How are they entered?

Comment: I've edited the question to explain why not "select '2/32' " and 'exactly as they are entered'. Thanks!

Comment: If those are columns in your table, you can use `concat(enrolled_people, '/', total_people)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the numerator and denominator are table columns then use:

```
select concat(numerator::text,'/',denominator::text) as "Fraction"
```

Comment: This works the best since it allows use of the table columns. Thank you Belayer!

Answer (score 2):

Use `concat()` instead of `to_char()`

```
select concat(2,'/',32) as "Fraction"
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=9aea240a534f02564e2055bbe9cc662c)